# sending an email from android programmatically, stops after closing compose page

Tags: java, android, gmail

I am trying to send email from android.

```
final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setClassName("com.google.android.gm", "com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail");
    emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "EMAIL CLIENt", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ "abc@gmail.com","xyz@gmail.com"});
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Help me !... Help Me....");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, turnONGps);
    startActivity(emailIntent);
```

The above piece of code opens the compose mail and enter all the details , but its not sending the mail.
I have updated manifest file as well.

Even I have removed

```
> emailIntent.setClassName("com.google.android.gm",
> "com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail");
```

even it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

This just open available application which can send emails, your app can't do it but itself, unless you will write your own the email client.

if after hit send email if not sending the email, the fault is in email client which you use to send it.

Comment: is there any example to explain a bit about custom email client

Comment: @bunta use JAVA Mail API